# Which of the different type of mobile apps has the worst access to native APIs ? and WHY?

Tags: java, api, mobile

my question is which of the different type of mobile apps has the worst access to native APIs ? and WHY?, the option is:Native Apps\Mobile Web Apps\Hybrid Apps.

And please give me a reason, thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Web Apps. U are relying on plugins to access native API's. Native Apps has the access to the API integrated in the native Language (java for android, objective c for iOS). Hybrid Apps: u can program the device dependant code in native. Mobile WEb, u need a plugin.